# Installing FLTK for Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, cmake, cygwin, codeblocks, fltk

Searching online I have found that there are several ways one can try to use FLTK, most common is to circumvent the IDE and use the supported software make for Visual Studio.

Others have mentioned the use of Cygwin (which I have no idea of what it is and would be grateful if someone could enlighten me on that).

On my attempt I have been following the tutorial from 
http://gintasdx.althirius-studios.com/2011/08/tutorial-codeblocks-with-fltk.html
Which uses CMake to 'build' the library (elaboration please) and from there I have to add the library files (not sure which files) to MinGW's lib directory.

Overall I haven't been able to make FLTK usable on C::B at the moment, and I need a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: what is unclear to you from the linked tutorial?

Comment: i have the built files, but when I open FLTK project in code::blocks, im asked to define the global variable 'fl' which i take 'base' to be the directory of the built files. But compiler provides 'undefined reference' errors.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind then. I have opted to try and use VS